# Comma with vocative "you"

Tags: vocative

Context: "And you, you little liar, if you..."

Should there be a comma between "you" and "little liar" and if no, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there should not be a comma there (as in "And you, **you, little liar**, if you..")

**You little liar** is a [vocative noun phrase](https://www.thoughtco.com/vocative-grammar-1692598) all by itself.  There is neither a need for a comma or any meaningful place for one in a phrase like *You + noun*.